# Azure AD Tenant = Organizational Account?

Tags: azure

I reading through various articles on how a headless app can authenticate with Azure.  I'm a little confused with the terminologies.  In this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless), it says it needs an Azure AD Tenant account.

My understanding is an Azure account can be a Microsoft account or an Organizational account.  Is Azure AD Tenant either of the two or is it just an Organizational account?  Can someone show me where this is clarified in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573650.aspx (See section `What is an Azure Tenant`):

> With the identity platform provided by Microsoft Azure, **a tenant is
>   simply a dedicated instance of Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) that
>   your organization receives and owns when it signs up for a Microsoft
>   cloud service such as Azure or Office 365**.

An Azure AD will have one or more users. These users could be native to that Azure AD, sourced from other Azure ADs (or even local AD) or could be Microsoft Accounts. AFAIK, as of today if a user account is not a Microsoft Account that means it is an organization account.

Answer (score 1):

An Azure tenant can be either of the two... and organizational account (often based on Office 365) or one based off a Microsoft Account (which is really just a user in a directory you don't control).

I'm a big fan of the "start from scratch" method - where you create tenant not tied to Office 365 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-howto-tenant/